# Javascript CLI: how to invoke bin file so that I can run integration tests with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, command-line-interface, integration-testing

I have created a command line interface that makes an API call to Google Books & allows for a user to search books using a keyword. The search returns a list of five books including a book ID that can be used to save the record to a reading list (written in a local file).

I would like to create some integration tests, but I am unsure of how to 'invoke' the program using the bin file that I have set up. Eventually I would like to test that user input results in the correct response from the programme, but the first thing I would need to test is that the initial command runs the programme.

Any help is much appreciated!

**package.json**

```
{
  ...

  "bin": {
    "books-cli": "bin/books-cli"
  },

  ...
}
```

**bin/books-cli**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('../')()
```

**index.js**

```
module.exports = () => {
  const args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));
  let command = args._[0] || 'help';

  if (args.help || args.h) {
    command = 'help';
  }

  if (args.version || args.v) {
    command = 'version';
  }

  switch (command) {
    case 'search':
      require('./commands/search')(args);
      break;
    case 'save':
      require('./commands/save')(args);
      break;
    case 'list':
      require('./commands/list')(args);
      break;
    case 'help':
      require('./commands/help')(args);
      break;
    case 'version':
      require('./commands/version')(args);
      break;
    default:
      console.error(
        `Sorry, "${command}" is not a valid command. Please type 'books-cli help' to see the help menu.`
      );
      break;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the binary from your `package.json` and spawn a [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and then write assertions

for example (not tested):

**`books-cli.spec.js`**

```js
const { bin: { books-cli }} = require('package.json');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

describe('books-cli', () => {
  describe('help', () => {
    let error;
    let result;
    beforeAll(done => {
      exec(`${books-cli} help`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        error = stderr;
        result = stdout;
        // let jest know when the process finishes execution
        // so all the tests below will be run with error and 
        // result populated
        done();
      });
    });
    it('should not result an error', () => {
      expect(error).toEqual('.....');
    });

    it('should output helpful information', () => {
      expect(result).toEqual('....');
    });

    // describe the rest of the commands
    describe('search');
    describe('save');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give it a go.